# Why did my book consider the ratio $7:5$ when it also could've considered $5:7$? Was it just a matter of choice?

Tags: solution-verification, vectors, physics, classical-mechanics, statics

**Question:**

Four forces $P$, $2P$, $3P$, and $4P$ act respectively along the sides of a square taken in order. Find the magnitude, direction, and line of action of their resultant.

**My book's attempt:**

[image: enter link description here]

**(All of the following can be ignored. Just skip to the concluding paragraph: look for "Start reading from here" and read from there onwards)**

The resultant of unlike parallel forces $3P$ and $P$ is $2P$, which acts along $EF||CD$ cutting $AD$ produced to $E$ such that,

$$P\cdot AE=3P\cdot DE$$

$$AD+DE=3DE$$

$$DE=\frac{1}{2}AD$$

$$DE=\frac{1}{2}a,\ \text{where $a=$ each side of the square}$$

Again the resultant of unlike parallel forces $4P$ and $2P$ is $2P$, which acts along $OG||DA$ cutting $BA$ produced to $G$ such that,

$$2P\cdot BG=4P\cdot AG$$

$$AB+AG=2AG$$

$$AG=AB=a$$

Let $EF$ and $OG$ meet at $O$. Then the resultant of the four forces is

$$\sqrt{(2P)^2+(2P)^2}$$

$$=2\sqrt{2}P$$

which acts along $OH$ and bisects $\angle GOF$. If $AG$ (produced) meets $OH$ at $H$,

$$AH=AG+GH$$

$$=a+OG$$

$$=a+AE$$

$$=a+a+0.5a$$

$$=\frac{5}{2}a$$

and,

$$BH=AH+AB$$

$$=\frac{5}{2}a+a$$

$$=\frac{7}{2}a$$

Now,

$$BH:AH=\frac{7}{2}a:\frac{5}{2}a$$

$$=7:5$$

**(Start reading from here)**

The magnitude of the resultant of the given forces is $2\sqrt{2}P$, and the line of action of the resultant is parallel to the diagonal that is drawn through the point of intersection of the lines of action of the forces $2P$ and $3P$, and the line of action of the resultant divides the side of the square along which $P$ amount of force acts externally from the opposite direction in the ratio $7:5$ (Ans.)

**My comments:**

The line of action of the resultant divides the side of the square along which $P$ amount of force acts externally from the opposite direction in the ratio $7:5$. This just means that $OH$ divides $BA$ externally in the ratio $7:5$. My question is, why did the book divide $BA$ by $OH$ externally? Why couldn't the book just divide $AB$ by $OH$ externally? Then the ratio would've been $5:7$. I saw another book, and they also divided $BA$ by $OH$. Why did the book have to divide externally from the opposite direction?

**My question:**

1. Why did $OH$ divide $BA$ externally instead of $OH$ dividing $AB$ externally? If I divided $AB$ by $OH$ would my answer be acceptable?

Comment: Note: cross-posted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/699162/44126

Comment: I believe, your answer should be treated as correct, if you obtained $BH:AH=7:5$, if only the question was not about ratio of dividing of specific edge.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu "I believe, your answer should be treated as correct, if you obtained $BH: AH=7:5$" - Sir, I think you mean $AH: BH=5:7$. My book said the answer is $BH: AH=7:5$. I asked in my question whether $AH: BH=7:5$ be treated as the answer or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, as you say, we have the following equivalent sentences:

- The segment $OH$ divides externally the segment $BA$ in a $BH$:$HA$=$7$:$5$ ratio,
- The segment $OH$ divides externally the segment $AB$ in a $AH$:$HB$=$5$:$7$ ratio.

Some minos comments

- Ratios are for *segments* *magnitudes*, not *vectors*. Hence, some authors will write the external ratio $BH$:$HA$=$7$:$5$ as $BH$:$AH$=$7$:$5$, $HB$:$HA$=$7$:$5$ or even using negative signs to reflect the external ratio $BH$:$HA$=$-7$:$5$. All of them are ratios of *magnitudes*.  Remembering that ratios are for segment and not for vectors should help. If you really wish to take *vectors* ratios, just go into **$\mathbb{C}$omplex numbers**.

Some following observations:

- The question "find the line of action of their resultant" is bad formulated, since there are *four* different lines of action, which will lead to one *net force* plus a *net momentum*, so depending the point of reference you choose to express the *net force*, the corresponding *net momentum* will be calculated accordingly. Hence the concept "resultant line of action" is absolutely wrong.
- A completely different issue is there is a mechanical reason to consider a third object reacting at point $O$. Hence, taking the point $O$ as reference, you indeed have a net force, and a momentum. But again, you do not have a "resultant line of action". As always, you have a *net force* plus a *net momentum*.